# How to assign dynamic variable to attribute using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to assign the dynamic value to attribute using Angular.js. Here is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="mul in mulImage">
  <a ng-href="attchImage{{$index}}" data-spzoom data-spzoom-width="400" data-spzoom-height="400"></a>
</div>
```

Here I am trying to assign some link to the anchor tag in controller side:

```
$scope.onLInkSelect = function(index) {
   atchVar='attchImage'+ index;
   $scope[atchVar]="http://localhost/test/abc.jpg";
}
```

Here `index` parameter is containing the value `0,1,2,3,4....`. Here I can not get the result as per expected.

Comment: The contents in `ng-href` is not interpolated the way you seem to be assuming. Consider the following: `<a ng-href="http://example.com/{{link}}">some text</a>` (only the `link` part gets interpolated. )  Also since you are already iterating through an array, why not use that? i.e:  `ng-href="{{mul.link}}"`

Comment: Since the code doesn't work, it is had to tell what it is meant to do. Right now it displays nothing. What do you want it to show to the user? How do you want the user to intereact with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.arr = ['link1', 'link2', ...]

<div ng-repeat="a in arr">
  <a ng-href="{{a}}">link: {{a}}</a>
</div>

<a ng-href="{{arr[1]}}"></a>
<a ng-href="{{arr[1] + '/smth'}}"></a>
```

etc.

Comment: I could not understand your answer.

Comment: No need in making variables a1, a2, a3... Make array with variables